# CSS Height width for Samsung A11

Tags: css, media-queries, resolution, screen-resolution

I want to test my Website in Samsung A11 screen size can anyone tell me its css height and width.
And also how to calculate css `height` and `width` using mobile screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of the screen is 720x1560 pixels. You can use flexbox in order to make your content reponsive to different types of screens.

Comment: I know the screen resolution but I want its CSS view ports